# Backup Database( .sdf) file to skydrive by changing it to .txt

Tags: backup, isolatedstorage, onedrive

I'm a beginner programmer. I have a database file (MyDatabase.sdf) in my windows phone mango app. What I am trying to accomplish is copy and convert the MyDatabase.sdf file as MyDatabaseBackup.txt in isolated storage and then upload it to skydrive as backup. Since skydrive doesn't support .sdf files to be uploaded some people have suggested this conversion method and have got it to work.
So I am trying to do the same but I'm unable to copy the .sdf file to .txt file in isolated storage. Here's my code...

```
//START BACKUP
    private void Backup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (client == null || client.Session == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must sign in first.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to backup? This will overwrite your old backup file!", "Backup?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                UploadFile();
        }
    }

    public void UploadFile()
    {
        if (skyDriveFolderID != string.Empty) //the folder must exist, it should have already been created
        {
            this.client.UploadCompleted
                += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(ISFile_UploadCompleted);

            infoTextBlock.Text = "Uploading backup...";
            dateTextBlock.Text = "";

            using (AppDataContext appDB = new AppDataContext(AppDataContext.DBConnectionString))
            {
                appDB.Dispose();
            }

            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("MyDatabase.sdf"))
                    {
                        myIsolatedStorage.CopyFile("MyDatabase.sdf", "MyDatabaseBackup.txt"); //This is where it goes to the catch statement.
                    }

                    this.client.UploadAsync(skyDriveFolderID, fileName, true, readStream , null);
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error accessing IsolatedStorage. Please close the app and re-open it, and then try backing up again!", "Backup Failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                infoTextBlock.Text = "Error. Close the app and start again.";
                dateTextBlock.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ISFile_UploadCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Error == null)
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Backup complete.";

            dateTextBlock.Text = "Checking for new backup...";

            //get the newly created fileID's (it will update the time too, and enable restoring)
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
            client.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(getFiles_GetCompleted);
            client.GetAsync(skyDriveFolderID + "/files");
        }
        else
        {
            this.infoTextBlock.Text =
                "Error uploading file: " + args.Error.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Here's how I am creating the database in my app.xaml.cs file.

```
// Specify the local database connection string.
        string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/MyDatabase.sdf";

        // Create the database if it does not exist.
        using (AppDataContext appDB = new AppDataContext(AppDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (appDB.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                //Create the database
                appDB.CreateDatabase();

                appDB.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

Some have suggested that make sure "no processes/functions/threads have the sdf file open." 
I tried to that in the UploadFile() method but I am not entirely sure if I did it correctly.

Can someone please give some code help on these two issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, create the local copy using File.Copy method as shown below, then upload the .txt file:

```
File.Copy (Path.Combine ([DbFileDir], MyDatabase.sdf), Path.Combine ([SomeLocalDir], MyDatabaseBackup.txt), true)
```

Note: you have to have proper access rights to the original/new local folders.
Hope this will help. Rgds,